# Node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am using minicube, I have only one node.

I am using local storage for data.

StorageClass and PersistentVolume

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-storage
  namespace: app
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mongodb-pv
  namespace: app
spec:
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: local-storage
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /data/mongodb
```

StatefulSet

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongodb
  namespace: app
spec:
  serviceName: mongodb-service
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      serviceAccount: mongodb-account
      containers:
        - name: mongodb
          image: mongo
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-data
              mountPath: /data/db
          env:
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secrets
                  key: mongodb-root-username
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secrets
                  key: mongodb-root-password
          command: ["/bin/sh"]
          args: ["-c", "mongod --replSet=rs0 --bind_ip_all"]
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: mongo-data
    spec:
      storageClassName: local-storage
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 5Gi
```

First replica is running fine, but the second one is still in pending status.

Describe printing this message:

Warning  FailedScheduling  4m56s (x2 over 9m56s)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling..

What can be the issue?

Comment: I'd delete the manually-created `StorageClass` and `PersistentVolume`, and also delete the `storageClassName` reference in the StatefulSet.  Minikube should be able to [provision storage on its own](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/persistent_volumes/#dynamic-provisioning-and-csi) when it sees a PersistentVolumeClaim.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#local), currently the local volumes doesn't support dynamic provisioning of `StorageClass: local-storage` , even if you can create the StorageClass. Alternatively, you can use the `StorageClass: standard` for your statefulset or you can also follow [operations on how to manage local volumes in your kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-storage-local-static-provisioner/blob/master/docs/operations.md).